# Use $.getJSON to replace city in $_GET to latitude and longtitude

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have this JavaScript code:

```
function jsnCoord(callback) {
    $.getJSON('https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&limit=1', {city: $('[name=search-value]').val()}, function (data) {
        callback(data[0]);
    });
}

function getCoord(val) {
    alert('Do something with ' + val.lat + ' here!');
}
```

I type city name to input and submit GET form. Then I want to get longtitude and latitude from my $_GET['cityname'] param and save it to php variables. How can i do that with my js functions, when function with $.getJSON can't return data without callback? Thanks

Comment: you'd need to implement an ajax call inside the `getJson` success-callback to send the (received) data back to server/php. So where you now have `callback()`, there the ajax would live.

Comment: But (I think) it would be easier anyway to send only the city to the server and let php make a curl to openstreetmap api to fetch lat/long

Comment: So don't use js for this? :)

Comment: You can of course, and there's nothing bad/wrong about it. It's only my opinion to be easier on the server.

Comment: Thanks. But in this case, i prefer client-side. Can you explain me calling ajax in callback?

Comment: create a `$.ajax('yourphpscript.php',....)` instead of the line `callback..`. Or a simple [$.post(..)](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) would also do (instead of ajax).

Comment: Thank you very much